# Node .fs Working with a HUGE Directory

Tags: node.js, file, fs

Picture a directory with a ton of files. As a rough gauge of magnitude I think the most that we've seen so far is a couple of million but it could technically go another order higher. Using node, I would like to read files from this directory, process them (upload them, basically), and then move them out of the directory. Pretty simple. New files are constantly being added while the application is running, and my job (like a man on a sinking ship holding a bucket) is to empty this directory as fast as it's being filled.

So what are my options? `fs.readdir` is [not ideal](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/388), it loads all of the filenames into memory which becomes a problem at this kind of scale. Especially as new files are being added all the time and so it would require repeated calls. (As an aside for anybody referring to this in the future, there is [something](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/583) being proposed to address this whole issue which may or may not have been realised within your timeline.)

I've looked at the myriad of fs drop-ins (graceful-fs, chokadir, readdirp, etc), none of which have this particular use-case within their remit.

I've also come across a couple of people suggesting that this can be handled with `child_process`, and there's a wrapper called [inotifywait](https://github.com/Inist-CNRS/node-inotifywait) which tasks itself with exactly what I am asking but I really don't understand how this addresses the underlying problem, especially at this scale.

I'm wondering if what I really need to do is find a way to just get the first file (or, realistically, batch of files) from the directory without having the overhead of reading the entire directory structure into memory. Some sort of stream that could be terminated after a certain number of files had been read? I know Go has a parameter for reading the first *n* files from a directory but I can't find a node equivalent, has anybody here come across one or have any interesting ideas? Left-field solutions more than welcome at this point!

Comment: To be honest, my gut instinct would be to write something in C / C++ to create a "readDirStream" of some sort.  Glancing through the Linux docs, [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) seems to do roughly what you're looking for.  You should be able to use [Node's Addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) to interface with the C calls.  If you can create a stream interface around the C calls, you should be good to go.

Comment: When you first run your script, is there already a lot of files waiting for you in the directory? Is the script expected to do more processing with the files than just copy from one directory to another? Is there a naming convention for the file names? Some kind of patter for a file name?

Comment: Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-dir-stream

Comment: useful so http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120077/the-ls-command-is-not-working-for-a-directory-with-a-huge-number-of-files Now, as i m unable to do C/C++, i d use php and opendir fn.... : ) http://php.net/opendir

Comment: @tiblu Yeah, unfortunately at application entry-point the directory could have 0 files with all yet to arrive or all files with none yet to arrive (or anything in-between). The processing layer is uploading the files so there is separate pooling/queuing functionality for that, we only go back to the directory and grab another batch when this queue starts to empty. And yeah, I have been toying with the idea of working from file-name assumptions but with this specific problem it opens up a horrible rabbit-hole of edge cases.

Comment: @SLaks That looks interesting, have you used it?

Comment: @DomVinyard How does ``fs.watch``/ ``inotifywait`` fail for your case? Did you try? Seems like just the case you want - event pops for each new file added/deleted, from there you could do whatever. Just trying to figure out if there was a specific problem under your "HUGE directory" condition.

Comment: @tiblu No, I haven't yet. It's not been updated for a couple of years or much adopted, I figured I'd throw this question out to test the waters of various avenues before I spent a day trying to understand how child_process works and whether this route is fit for production. I will explore further on your recommendation.

Comment: @DomVinyard I'm not sure you need the ``child_process`` to get started. Just try with plain ``fs.watch``(https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) / ``inotifywait``. I guess the ``child_process`` was suggested to list the directory contents by executing a raw command to avoid memory issues related to ``fs.readdir``, but you don't need it if ``fs.watch`` / ``inotifywait`` will pop an event for every directory modification.

Comment: @tiblu Alas fs.watch has some major problems - as per the docs "The fs.watch API is not 100% consistent across platforms, and is unavailable in some situations." and also "watching files or directories on network file systems (NFS, SMB, etc.) often doesn't work reliably or at all." In fact, the person that I'm inheriting this project from told me that they were indeed using native fs.watch initially but had to abandon it for these reasons (specifically the network case). I think child_process may mitigates some of this but I'm not optimistic that it's a complete solution.

Comment: @DomVinyard I see. Sure it depends if in reality the platform independence is actually needed or not. But yes, NFS and SMB make the situation sketchy. What processing does the Node.JS script actually do? It only copies to single destination or partitions the files somehow or something else? Knowing the logic has an impact on the solutions to consider. I think we should move this discussion to a chat.

Comment: @tiblu In this case it uploads them to S3 and increments a stats object, although for the sake of a high quality re-usable Stack Overflow discussion I think probably better to assume that this is an isolated general purpose problem. (Great idea, but I'm getting a 'could not move this discussion to chat' error!?)

Comment: @DomVinyard Threw an error for me also, but I created the chat manually - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112364/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-37285736-node-fs-working-with-a-huge-directory

Comment: @DomVinyard Did you ever found a solution to this problem? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your operation system listing file command, and stream the result into NodeJS.

For example in Linux:

```
var cp=require('child_process')
var stdout=cp.exec('ls').stdout

stdout.on('data',function(a){
         console.log(a)
});0
```

RunKit: https://runkit.com/aminanadav/57da243180f3bb140059a31d